# How to declare two outbound-channel-adapter for publishing different message

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

I have declared int:chain with single input and output channel,

```
<int:chain input-channel="InputChannel" output-channel="Channel">

      <int:transformer method = "transform" >
        <bean class="com.sampleconverter" />
      </int:transformer>
        <int:service-activator method="transform">
             <bean class="com.Transformer" />
        </int:service-activator>
     <int:object-to-string-transformer />
   </int:chain>
```

How to declare multiple output-channel each having different transform methods (different messages)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Only one component in Spring Integration has multi output - `router`.

So, you can configure it in the end of the `chain` and let it to decide to which channel to send the message by the provided condition.

For example:

```
<payload-type-router>
    <mapping type="java.lang.String" channel="strings"/>
    <mapping type="java.lang.Number" channel="numbers"/>
</payload-type-router>
```

More info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router) and in the [Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/oddeven).